# Setting background image with react semantic ui

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

the image below is very disappointing.

i want to set the login form at the center and middle of the page and a blurred background image, but after putting the image, it went down.

i used zIndex but it did not work.

i am using react semantic ui, and not sure how to implement this. i am relatively new to this framework.

doing things directly with html and css would've done the trick.

pls view the image provided.
thanks guys!!!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaMux.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Grid, Header, Form, 
  Segment, Button, Divider, Image } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class LoginView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

      // <div style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
      <div>
        <style>
          {`
            body > div,
            body > div > div,
            body > div > div > div.login-form {
              height: 100%;
            }`
          }
        </style>

        <Image style={{ zIndex: 0 }} fluid src='/images/home.gif' />

        <Grid style={{ zIndex: 1 }}
          textAlign='center'
          style={{ height: '100%' }}
          verticalAlign='middle'
          >
          <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
            <Segment piled style={{ paddingTop: '2em', paddingBottom: '2em' }}>
              <Header textAlign='center'>
                <Header.Subheader>
                  HELLO, FRIEND!
                </Header.Subheader>
                <div>
                  Login to your <i>mnmltaskr</i> account
                </div>
              </Header>
              <Form>
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  icon='user'
                  iconPosition='left'
                  placeholder='Email address' />
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  icon='lock'
                  iconPosition='left'
                  placeholder='Password'
                  type='password' />

                <Button fluid>Login</Button>
              </Form>
              <Divider />
              <Button basic fluid>Sign up instead</Button>
            </Segment>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Could we have a bit of code please ?

Comment: oh i'm sorry, i forgot to paste it.